# automatically appending messages from server to the div tag

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, websocket

I am trying to get together a simple prototype:

- page with a text field and an empty div tag
- same above page opened in two browser windows
- Browser 1 -  user A types something in the text field and presses enter
- Browser 2 - user B, without refreshing the page, sees what user A typed

I know AJAX would be used but I am looking for a detailed solution.  jQuery? WebSockets? nodeJS?

If I use jQuery I feel I will have to make periodic requests to the server to see if any new messages came in, rather than this I want this to be instant.

are there any nodeJS examples along these lines?

Comment: if u r getting the solution I hope u will share it .

Answer (score 0):

You have to look into [**reverse ajax**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Ajax). Read [**Reverse Ajax Technique**](http://www.ajaxwith.com/Reverse-Ajax-Technique.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get instant notifications from the server sent to the client, as HTTP connection established only from the client to the server even if kept alive, client must start request first, which means you need to do a periodic check to know if there is some updates.